# Empty RecyclerView on Switching between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement `tablayout` in a `fragment` which is already part of `BottomNavigationView`, I am facing a problem while navigating through navigation bar, There is a `recycler view` in a `fragment` which is the part of `tablayout`, now when I navigate between fragments via `BottomNavigation` the `recyclerview` becomes empty, and there is nothing in the `logcat`.

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView navigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        initComponent();

        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

    }

    private void initComponent() {


        navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);


        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

               // ViewAnimation.fadeOutIn(fragme);

                Fragment fragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home_main:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.search:
                        fragment = new SearchFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.notifications:
                        fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                        break;

                    case R.id.favourite:
                        fragment = new FavouriteFragment();
                        break;
                }

                return loadFragment(fragment);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.bt_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }



    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        if (fragment != null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager view_pager;
    private TabLayout tab_layout;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

        view_pager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        setupViewPager(view_pager);

        tab_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager);

        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());



        adapter.addFragment(new PresetsFragment(), "Presets");
/*        adapter.addFragment(new PresetsFragment(), "Tutorials");
        adapter.addFragment(new PresetsFragment(), "Categories");*/
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tab_layout = null;
        view_pager = null;
    }
```

**PresetsFragment**

```
public class PresetsFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    PresetsAdapter presetsAdapter;

    String[] presetList = {"s", "s", "d", "d"};


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_presets, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.presetsRecyclerView);

        presetsAdapter = new PresetsAdapter(presetList, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(presetsAdapter);
        //presetsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }
}
```

I have spent so many hours to figure it out but still unable to get it..

Comment: `PresetsFragment` -> maybe try to move the adapter and recycler initialization to the `onViewCreated()` method

Comment: Your problem is that the images take a few seconds to load, right?

Comment: No its not taking few seconds, its completely empty when I come back to that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your `loadFragment` method you are using `FrameLayout` and replacing fragment on `BottomNavigation` selection when you do so you are creating a new fragment every time if you used a `ViewPager` it will work fine with you